# Lucene.net matchphase query doesn't work

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to use match phrase query, but it keeps yielding no results. What did I do wrong here? I use Lucene.net 3.0.3

```
using (var dir = new RAMDirectory())
            {
                var queryText = "Bruce Wayne";
                Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

                var sampleDocs = new SortedSet<String>() { "Bruce Wayne", "Wayne Bruce", "Bruce Batman Wayne" };

                using (var writer = new IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, create: true, mfl: IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED))
                {
                    foreach (var sampleDoc in sampleDocs)
                    {
                        var doc = new Document();
                        doc.Add(new Field("id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                        doc.Add(new Field("name", sampleDoc, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));

                        writer.AddDocument(doc);
                    }
                }

                var searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);

                var query = new PhraseQuery()
                {
                    Slop = 2
                };

                foreach (var item in queryText.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query.Add(new Term("name", item));
                }

                TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(query, 1000);
            }
```

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me (using `queryText = "bruce wayne"` I get three results).  Could the problem be that you aren't considering analysis?  "Bruce Wayne", for instance, wouldn't get any results, due to the capitals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I forgot to lowercase the query text